# Sum(case results not right

Tags: sql, sum, case

I have a contact table that includes the length of time each contact lived in the neighborhood:

```
 ID    First_Name   Last_Name    Neighborhood_Time
 1      John         Smith        1-2 years
 2      Mary         Jones        2-5 years
 3      Dennis       White        2-5 years
 4      Martha       Olson        5+ years
 5      Jeff         Black        5+ years
 6      Jean         Rogers       2-5 years
```

I want to show the percentage of time, the result would look like this:

```
 One_to_2_Years   Two_to_5_Years       5+_Years
      16                50                 33
```

This is what I'm using:

```
 select 
 sum(case when Neighborhoods_time ='1-2 years' then 1 else 0 end)*100/(select count(*) from contact) as One_to_2_Years,    
 sum(case when Neighborhoods_time ='2-5 years' then 1 else 0 end)*100/(select count(*) from contact) as Two_to_6_Years,
 sum(case when Neighborhoods_time ='5+years' then 1 else 0 end)*100/(select count(*) from contact) as Six_to_10_Years
  from dbo.contact
```

This is my result:

```
  One_to_2_Years   Two_to_5_Years       5+_Years
        0               0                  16
        16              33                 0
        0               16                 16
```

I see the numbers under each column are correct, I'm having a problem summing them.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to use `/(select count(*) from contact)` in each column, just use `/ count(*) AS ` as you are already selecting from `contact`

Comment: Thanks Nicola, you're correct.

Comment: @GarethD Thanks for making it easier.

Answer (score 0):

Add Group by Neighborhoods_time

Answer (score 0):

The basis of your query can be produced like

```
select 
    Neighborhood_Time,
    100*COUNT(*)/(Select COUNT(*) from contact) as percentvalue
from 
    contact
group by 
    Neighborhood_Time
```

If you want to arrange it horizontally, then you should use a pivot

```
select
*
from
(
select 
    Neighborhood_Time,
    100*COUNT(*)/(Select COUNT(*) from contact) as percentvalue
from 
    contact
group by 
    Neighborhood_Time
) src
PIVOT
( SUM(percentvalue) for Neighborhood_Time in ([1-2 years],[2-5 years],[5+ years])) as pt
```